# Using a Jquery loading bar on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

w=Hi all, what I am trying to achieve is the animation of a progress bar namely .progress div from 0% width on document.ready to 100% width on document.load however I want this to be animated smoothly - I have a feeling this could be done via CSS but it is not cross browser and at the moment I the width of .progress div goes nearly directly to 100% width. Its containing div #overlay will also fade on document.ready... Any ideas?
Heres what I have at the moment;

CSS

```
.progress {
        width: 100%;
        height: 4px;
        background: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        text-align: left;
}

.progress div {
       background: #000;
}
```

JQuery

```
var progress = $('.progress div');

$(window).ready(function(){
    progress.css('width','0'+'%');

}); 

$(window).load(function(){
    //Set width to 100%
    progress.css('width','100'+'%');

   // PAGE IS FULLY LOADED  
   // FADE OUT YOUR OVERLAYING DIV
   $('#overlay').fadeOut();

});
```

HTML

```
    <div id="overlay">
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="bar"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="logo">
        <img src="images/logo.png">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help ;)

### EDIT

I have tried using css transitions however the same scenario happens, their just goes straight to 100% instead of going over 4s as stated in the transition statement - this is show below

```
 -webkit-transition: width 500ms ease-out 1s;
        -moz-transition: width 500ms ease-out 1s;
        -o-transition: width 500ms ease-out 1s;
        transition: width 500ms ease-out 1s;
}
```

Comment: This isn't an easy question, so you can use [Pace](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/)

Comment: Just an FYI, you don't need to use 'progress.css('width','0'+'%');', use 'progress.css('width','0%');' and if your targeting the .bar div, your variable should be 'var progress = $('.progress .bar');'. See my fiddle below using '$().animate();'

Answer (score 1):

Use animate

[jsfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/Lhj8pprb/2/)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
var progress = $('.progress .bar');
//Set width to 100%
progress.animate({
  width:'100%'
}, 2000);
setTimeout(function() {
 $('#overlay').fadeOut();
}, 4000);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it shoots right to 100% is because there is no intermediary between document-ready to window-loaded.

Your JS doesn't have an event to say "Im XYZ% done loading the objects".    The *browser* does - but it's still doing a *LOT* of work to do that integration (getting the headers for all elements on the page, their file sizes, and the sum as it all comes in).    But none of that is exposed to the javascript - that's internal browser engine code.

So you have just one step - from dom-ready to window-loaded - that's why it fires up.    The other guy answering your question using a setTimeOut is just *simulating* a percentage loading - it's not a true representation of the actual percentage.

Unfortunately, you'll never get it.   Unless you're doing a lot of REST calls, AJAX calls and loading your objects atomically -- you can sort of simulate it by "I'm loading 10 objects via REST/AJAX/OWIN [please don't] -- trigger a bump up each time one is done" sort of thing.

Comment: True, it is simulating, but coding the actual progress of loading each element is a monumental task for even a very experienced coder. In reality, if one can simulate it easily with a few lines of code and a setTimeout, why code the actual loading?

Comment: I'd never recommend anyone coding the actual loading.  Defeats the purpose of the browser.    What I was suggesting is, and only if he did it this way, had lots of REST/AJAX/JSON objects coming back - lots of calls - to do like, "i have 10 calls - each time one is done, increment bar 10%".    Not for individual CSS, JS, GIF, JPG, HTML files.      The problem with your solution is that if a tiny GIF hangs for 20 seconds or a resource takes forever - the progressbar will be 100% long before it really is 100%.  That doesn't seem like an acceptable alternative (usability) versus just not doing it.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of web pages that follow this unacceptable alternative.